# Como formateo una fecha por medio de javascript

Tags: javascript

Necesito formatear esta fecha "**20181231**" que dicho numero viene dentro una variable llamada "**FechaAlta**" por medio de un script y convertirla **31/12/2018**

yo habia generado un script pero creo que es medio erroneo:

```js
var str = RentaFinancieraPlazoFijo.FechaAlta;
var anioC = "20";
var dia = str.substring(0, 2);
var mes = str.substring(3, 5);
var anio = str.substring(6, 8);
var resp= anioC + anio + mes + dia;
resp;
```

Comment: lo ideal es que modififique la pregunta que ya hicistes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Así es como me funcionó.

```js
function convertirFecha(date) {
    var year = date.substring(0,4);
    var month = date.substring(4,6);
    var day = date.substring(6,8);
    var convertedDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year
    console.log(convertedDate);
    return convertedDate;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="convertirFecha('20181231');">Clic</button>
```

Comment: Creo que solo sería agregar un return a la función y quedaría.

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que la fecha en formato string vendra siempre de la misma forma
intenta lo siguiente

```js
  

var str ="20181231";

var anio = str.substring(0, 4);
var mes = str.substring(4, 6);
var dia = str.substring(6, 8);

var resp=dia+"/"+mes+"/"+anio; //fecha tipo string
 console.log(resp);//'31/12/2018'
var date= new Date(anio,mes-1,dia);  // tipo fecha
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentarlo con la librería [momentsjs](https://momentjs.com)

```js
var t = moment('20181231').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
console.log(t)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```