# Como agregar enteros y decimales por medio de javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xsd

Hola como puedo transformar una variable "RentaFinancieraTitulosValores.ClausuladeAjuste;" que trae un datos numericos 2323265959 y agregarlo como enteros y decimales por medio de javascript. tome un ejemplo que vi pero no estoy logrando buscarle la vuelta.

```js
var numero = RentaFinancieraTitulosValores.ClausuladeAjuste; 
var numeroPos ="";
var numeroNeg ="";
var esPos = 1;

if (numero >=0) {
 esPos = 1;
}else{
 esPos = 0;
}

parteEntera = Number(numero.substring(0, numero.length - 2)).toString();
parteDecimal = numero.substring(numero.length - 2, numero.length);
numero = parteEntera + ',' + parteDecimal;
var miles=new RegExp("(-?[0-9]+)([0-9]{3})");
while(miles.test(numero)) {
 numero=numero.replace(miles, "$1" + '.' + "$2"); 
} 

if(esPos){
 numeroPos = numero;
}else{
 numeroNeg = '';   
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ser más específico con la finalidad de que es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: quiero convertir por medio de js un numero entero y pasarlo por ej a 1.000.000,00

Comment: Javascript agrego NumberFormat aqui un ejemplo `console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('es-en').format(20000000))` asi te evitas el pattern

Comment: emm no pero no se si es eso lo que quiero

Comment: prefieres hacer un `regex`??, solo debes validar que se numerico y que no sea NaN

Comment: quizas algo parecido al ejemplo que adjunte la variable RentaFinancieraTitulosValores.ClausuladeAjuste va a traer como dato unos numeros que no traen ni puntos ni comas

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Como formateo una fecha por medio de javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/263540/como-formateo-una-fecha-por-medio-de-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagino que lo que deseas es algo como esto:

```js
function numberToPointedString(number){
    
    const coma = number.toString().indexOf(".") !== -1 ? true : false;
    const arrayNumero = coma ? 
          number.toString().split(".") : 
          number.toString().split("");
    let integerPart = coma ? arrayNumero[0].split("") : arrayNumero;
    let floatPart = coma ? arrayNumero[1] : null;
    let result;
    let subIndex = 1;
  
    for(let i = integerPart.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      
      if(integerPart[i] !== "." && subIndex % 3 === 0 && i != 0){
         
         integerPart.splice(i, 0, ".");
         subIndex++;
         
      }else{
        
        subIndex++;
        
      }
      
    }
  
    integerPart = integerPart.toString();
    integerPart = integerPart.replace(/,/gi,"");
    result = coma ? integerPart + "," + floatPart : integerPart;
    return result;
  
}

console.log(numberToPointedString(12345678.24));
```

La explicación del código es un  poco larga y tediosa, pero la haré:

la constante coma sera verdadera solo si se encuentra que el **numero** pasado como atributo de la función tiene un punto, es decir es decimal, de lo contrario será false su contenido.

el arreglo arrayNumero es el resultado de dividir la parte entera de la parte decimal en un arreglo (Si es que existe la parte decimal), esto es hecho usando el punto del numero como divisor junto con la función split, si el numero introducido no es decimal, entonces simplemente convertimos todo el numero a un array de numeros y lo almacenamos.

integerPart simplemente almacena cada uno de los digitos almacenados como un array ej: 1560.65 sería [1,5,6,0].

floatPart almacena la parte decimal del numero original pero **EN FORMA DE STRING**, en caso de que el numero original no fuese decimal, entonces almacena null.

result almacenará el numero ya convertido.

subIndex es un "contador" especial que se usará para saber cuando se debe insertar un "." como divisor cada 3 números de derecha a izquierda en el arreglo que contiene la parte entera.

Hacemos un ciclo for inverso, (Comienza desde el ultimo elemento hasta el primero), luego en cada iteración comprobamos varias cosas y todas deben cumplirse:

- Que i no sea 0 (Ya que nunca añadimos un . antes del comienzo del numero)
- Que el elemento actual del arreglo que contiene cada dígito de la parte entera de nuestro numero no sea un "." (No vamos a añadir un punto seguido de otro).
- Que el residuo de la división entre subIndex y 3 (Es decir su modulo en base 3), sea 0, es decir, estaremos comprobando que estemos agregando un "." cada 3 espacios de derecha a izquierda sin contar los "." agregados por nosotros en el ciclo.

Si se cumplen estas condiciones añadimos un "." en esa posición del arreglo e incrementaremos el valor de la variable subIndex en una unidad.

Si no se cumple alguna entonces simplemente añadimos una unidad a subIndex.

Una vez añadidos los puntos a nuestro arreglo de digitos enteros cada 3 espacios de derecha izquierda, convertiremos el arreglo a un string con la función toString(), pero al hacer esto quedaran caracteres (comas), no deseadas, por lo que luego con la función replace usando la expresión global /gi, reemplazaremos todas las comas por un caracter vació, que es lo mismo que borrar las comas.

después, dependiendo de si el numero inicialmente era decimal guardamos un valor u otro, si tiene parte decimal, concatenamos la parte entera convertida con una coma (",") y luego le concatenaremos la parte flotante y lo almacenaremos en la variable resultado.

si el numero no tiene parte decimal, simplemente almacenaremos en ella la parte entera convertida.

luego simplemente retornamos el resultado.

Comment: Excelente, ahora te hago una consulta, si el numero que debo convertir viene en una variable de tipo xml por ej: <tipo_cuenta>15151511518</tipo_cuenta> como podría convertirla?

Comment: crea una variable con cualquier nombre en la que almacenarás en ella la propiedad textContent de tu etiqueta html, para ello a esta le puedes poner un id, entonces guardas este valor haciendo algo como: document.getElementById("nombre del id que le diste").textContent;
Luego conviertes este valor a un flotante con parseFloat() y despues si quieres separar el numero original del convertido, creas otra variable que almacenará el resultado de ejecutar la función numberToPointedString pasandole como parámetro el valor del numero convertido a flotante.

Comment: perdón, quise decir de tu etiqueta XML.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function parseMil(price){
    var num = price;
    num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g,'$1.');
    num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/,'');
    return(num)
}

console.log(parseMil(12234))
```

Comment: Deberías explicar tu código, aunque la pregunta ya tiene una respuesta aceptada lo mejor es no responder únicamente con código. Saludos.